# Webscraping - why do I only get the LAST row in a HTML table? BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of HTML files I have in a folder on my computer. The data I want is stored in a table, and I'm able to get the last row in the table, from each, file, but the other rows are ignored!

I've copied parts of the HTML to Pastebin, here: http://pastebin.com/hajr8SFi

This is the code I have so far. Again, it works with the last row, but not the others. So I guess there's a problem with the loop? I've tried to figure it out, but no results so far :(

```
def processData( pageFile ):
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    f.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    ewo = soup.find_all("td", {"class":"date"})
    ewo2 = soup.find_all("td", {"class":"user"})
    ewo3 = soup.find_all("p", {"class":"single"})
fishs = [ ]
dogs = [ ]
rats = [ ]
for html in ewo:
    feedbacks = BeautifulSoup(str(html).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "") # convert the html to text
    fishs.append(feedbacks.encode("utf-8").strip())
for html2 in ewo2:
    feedbacks2 = BeautifulSoup(str(html2).strip()).get_text().encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "") # convert the html to text
    dogs.append(feedbacks2.encode("utf-8").strip())
    str1 = ''.join(dogs)
for html3 in ewo3:
    feedbacks3 = BeautifulSoup(str(html3).strip()).encode("utf-8").replace("\n", "") # convert the html to text
    rats.append(feedbacks3.encode("utf-8").split('<p class="single">')[1].split("</p>")[0].strip())
csvfile = open(today + ' evo.csv', 'ab')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
for fish, dog, rat in zip(fishs, dogs, rats):
    writer.writerow([fish, dog, rat])
csvfile.close()
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dir = "files/"
csvFile = today + " file.csv"
csvfile = open(csvFile, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(["F", "I", "V"])
csvfile.close()
fileList = os.listdir(dir)
totalLen = len(fileList)
count = 1
for htmlFile in fileList:
    path = os.path.join(dir, htmlFile) # get the file path
    processData(path) # process the data in the file
    print "Processed '" + path + "'(" + str(count) + "/" + str(totalLen) + ")..." # display status
    count = count + 1 # incriment counter
```

Comment: instead of using `BeautifulSoap`'s `find()`, make your llife easier by scraping the desired HTMl from soup by CSS Selectors like `soup.select("tr.your_class td#your_id")`

Comment: The code you have there isn't right. For example, your first for loop, says for html in ewo. However ewo hasn't been declared yet. First it's inside of a function, so that would be the scope, second that function isn't going to get executed until your last for loop. Maybe your indentions are off in your example? Are those for loops all supposed to be inside the processData function?